# Ignite ClusterNode.consistendId() returns value different from one that is defined in configuration

Tags: java, ignite

ClusterNode.consistentId() returns UUID instead of node name defined in configuration xml

Discovery spi configuration is this:

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="localAddress" value="myNode"/>
        <property name="localPort" value="48800"/>
        <property name="localPortRange" value="1"/>
        <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                <property name="addresses">
                    <list>
                        <value>myNode</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

I also have dataRegionConfigurations of dataStorageConfiguration defined in the xml, and when i remove this property, ClusterNode.consistentId() returns 127.0.0.1:48800 instead of UUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is by design. When node is persistent, default consistentId is calculated differently than on non-persistent node.

Why don't you specify consistentId explicitly if you want it be set to any specific value?